# Can RIA Service Project And client Silverlight application be separated?

Tags: wcf-data-services, silverlight-5.0, wcf-ria-services, prism-4, devart

So far all Silverlight RIA example, Tutorial I saw is they Write RIA Domain Services in projectname.Web and Give the WCF_RIA Project reference in Projectname Project which have silverlight code.

Now My question is can my Client take reference of some far project? like someone else have create a WCF RIA Service and i want to use it in my project. so I've to provide a URL and I can use. Or m'I getting Confuse with WCF services and WCF RIA Services?

My Silverlight Project is in Prism 4.1 , Silverlight 5. Now here I'm unable to Decide I should Use WCF Services, WCF RIA Services (DOAMIN SERVICES), WCF Data Service 5.6 ?

My applciation include Custom authentication autherization of Users, Maps & Grids etc.

http://www.silverlightshow.net/video/WCF-RIA-Services-Webinar-5.aspx

http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/WCF-RIA-Services-Part-10-Exposing-Domain-Services-To-Other-Clients.aspx

I think this second link is saying should go with WCF Services? 
so Doubtful situation.